# How can I create a new column which consists on the sum of two columns in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to put together 2 columns of a data frame, one is 'Date' and the other is 'Time', so I want to create a column called 'Date and Time'. My dataframe is called GLE_48. So I tried this:

```
GLE_48['Date and Time'] = GLE_48['Date']+GLE_48['Time']
```

To this, I get the following Error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'datetime.time'
```

I tried to solve it by applying the next tool:

```
GLE_48['Date and Time'] = GLE_48['Date']+GLE_48['Time'].map(pd.Timedelta.to_pytimedelta)
```

and I got:

```
'TypeError: descriptor 'to_pytimedelta' for 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas._Timedelta' objects doesn't apply to a 'datetime.time' object
```

So, I have been unable to do anything else, I am not very used to pandas yet, does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by using the next code:

```py
GLE_48["Date and Time"] = pd.to_datetime(GLE_48['Date'].astype(str) + GLE_48['Time'].astype(str), format="%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S")
```

I found it easier to turn the columns into 'string' type and then putting the columns together than turning the columns into the same 'datetime' format.